# Isomers with molecular formula C₄H₇Cl

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

What are the possible isomeric structures of chlorobutene $(\ce{C4H7Cl})?$

I've come up with seven:

- *cis*-1-chlorobut-1-ene
- *trans*-1-chlorobut-1-ene
- 2-chlorobut-1-ene
- 3-chlorobut-1-ene
- 1-chlorobut-2-ene
- *cis*-2-chlorobut-2-ene
- *trans*-2-chlorobut-2-ene

Comment: I can think of nine isomers.

Comment: Can you please suggest the two isomers I'm missing?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=C4H7Cl) can find the isomers of a given formula, quite nicely as well.

Comment: @AliCaglayan Quite nicely except that it misses two of them? (2 and 3 from orthocresol's figure in my answer) I assume that it is simply extracting from a database except that surely 1-Chloro-1-methylcyclopropane is in any reasonable db? Weird.

Comment: @gilleain I am having a hard time finding any literature on 1-Chloro-1-methylcyclopropane or 1-Chloro-2-methylcyclopropane which might mean that WA has not included it because there is no data on it?

Comment: @AliCaglayan Fair point. I suspect that it what WA is doing. It makes a lot of sense, actually to only return results about experimentally verified entities, and not just theoretical ones. It's just amusing to me that WA (which can do much more complex mathematics) doesn't just list all possible ones. EDIT: Well there's this paper: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00894a001 that talks about photchemical rearrangement of 2-methylallylchloride to 1-Chloro-1-methylcyclopropane

Answer (score 11):

There are 12 different constitutional isomers:

[image: Isomers]

There is also the further possibility of stereoisomerism in some of the compounds above.

- **3**: Two diastereomers (*cis*- and *trans*-) are possible.
- **7, 8, 9**: Geometrical isomerism is possible in these alkenes.
- **11**: C-3 (the carbon with the chlorine) is a chiral centre, which leads to two possible enantiomers.

That makes a total of 17 possible isomers.

Comment: And that's not counting the _cis/trans_ things.

Comment: I hope I didn't miss anything out.

Comment: @orthocresol much better answer than mine! Should be a way to transfer answers, I guess. Thanks

Comment: Well, you did the work finding the 12 constitutional isomers, I just touched it up a bit :)