# How many non-cyclic isomers exist for C4H7Br?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

> The compound **Q** has the formula $\ce{C4H7Br}$ and contains a double bond. How many non-cyclic isomers exist for **Q**? Should include cis-trans and any other form of isomers as well.

Comment: Homework. Add a list with all those you have found to your question, *then* we give hints as to what is missing.

Comment: I can count at least 12...

Comment: Also duplicate of [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/46606/50406)